# Preload images without affecting current page

Tags: javascript, html, image, preload, image-preloader

I am developing a component for an application that has an image with a variety of buttons on it.

When clicking a button, the image source changes. There are about 250 unique buttons (so 250 images).

When the application loads, I want to start preloading the images, however, I need priority to always be the actual image tag that the user sees. When I start preloading a bunch of images and click the button to change the image, it takes a long time before getting to the new image. Is there a way I can give priority to anything in the DOM and only load the preload images while nothing else is going on?

So far I have tried looping through the list of images and for each one creating an image in javascript and setting the source.

```
for (let i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
    let image = new Image();
    image.src = imageList[i].source;
}
```

I also tried prefetch links by looping through a list of my images and javascript and adding the links to the DOM.

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="(url)">
```

I get the same issues with both making the application very slow.

Comment: how big are the images? If they are small, you should probably consider another method of loading the images like a css sprite. Anytime you have that many images, the best option would be to lower the number of files that need loading.

Comment: They are large images, already compressed, they are still an average of 400kb.

Comment: You're preloading 100MB of images every time this page is loaded, just in case they're all accessed?

Comment: Perhaps you could preload an image while its thumbnail is being hovered over. That could be enough to alleviate the delay on click, without needing to preload 250 assets.